# Помогите приклеить футер к низу страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, itemtouchhelper

У меня контент уходит под футер. Помогите

[image: css]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> WayStore </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img class="graficlogo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
        </header>



        <main>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>              
                                <div class="button">
                            <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>              
                                <div class="button">
                            <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tovari_items">
                    <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                        <div class="tovar_list">
                            <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                <div id="price">
                                    <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                    </div>              
                                <div class="button">
                            <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </main>

        <footer>
            <div class="social">
                <p> Мы в социальных сетях! </p>
                    <div class="footer_social_img">
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_instagram.png"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_facebook.png"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_twitter.png"></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </footer>


    </body>

</html>

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.graficlogo {
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    background: #F6C010;
    margin: 0;
}

main {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  background: #1C1E1F;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #F6C010;
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    background: #F6C010;
    height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.footer_social_img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tovari_items {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tovari_items:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.tovar_list h3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#price h5 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F6C010;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buy {
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: #68D81E;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.buy:hover {
  background: #82F238;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты можешь прикрепить футер вот так:

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
footer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: а если страница будет в несколько экранов?

Answer (score 0):

```
footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не позволяет разобраться в решении, пожалуйста, дополните его пояснениями